# jump web page up and down

Tags: html, css

i built asp.net web site : http://shahidostovari.ir/

if you see it when you scrolling page up or down the web page is jump up or down !

i tested it on google chrome and firefox

i did not have this problem on localhost !

i use free template for my site !

how can i solve this problem ?

if the problem come from my html and css file , what should i do ?

did anybody have this problem before ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend removing your "nicescroll" plugin and seeing if the problem persists. You have some javascript that monitors the scroll event of your window that hides/shows things dynamically but I don't think that's the problem.

Remove the following from your main.js file in your theme:

```
var nice = $("html").niceScroll({
    scrollspeed: 60,
    zindex: "999999",
    background: "#fff",
    mousescrollstep: 40,
    cursoropacitymin: 0,
    cursoropacitymax: .5,
    cursorwidth: 15,
    cursorborder: 0,
    cursorcolor: '#000',
    cursorborderradius: 6,
    autohidemode: false,
    horizrailenabled: false

});
```

Comment: i removed that but still i have that problem

Comment: there isn't nobody know what should i do ?